# I can't replace a part of my EditText with a calculation...

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

The basic idea is to calculate the sin, cos, or tan of a value inputted by the user and set the part of the EditText that has the sin, cos, or tan command to the final calculation... ex. 1+sin3 ... desired output of EditText is 
"1+0.1411200081"

```
    String buffer2 = "" + bufferTerm;
    int length2 = buffer2.length();
    caller.screen.getText().replace(2, 5, buffer2,0,length2);
```

Now, to my problem, buffer2 **is** the correct value, but the editText doesn't end up being what I need it to be... it removes any decimals and/or negatives.
For instance in the above case, it outputs 1+01411200081.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong... any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: as i know you have to use  caller.screen.setText(caller.screen.getText().replace(2, 5, buffer2,0,length2)); you are just getting the string and editing that string not the text of edittext

Comment: No, that isn't the problem, I just tried it your way, and it outputted the same thing as before... 1+01411....

Comment: can you provide more information about the bufferTerm , also your edittext does it have some options that limits its content to numbers only or decimal only or something like that ?

Comment: numbers only... but when i just set it to a decimal number it still shows it... and bufferTerm is defined as the sin, cos, or tan (whichever specified) of the number inputted by the user.

Comment: try to put this property to the EditText 
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
this will allow it to put signed decimal numbers

Comment: Just tried it... doesn't work... I think it's an error in the third line not the formatting of the editTexy

Comment: And by doesn't work I mean to say... still the same result

Comment: Also... if I do           caller.screen.getText().replace(2, 5, buffer2, 1, length2);

Comment: It cuts off the starting 1 and replaces it with a decimal

Comment: can you describe the replace method or where can i find it , I didn't saw that method in the String class

Comment: It is an EditText method... I'm pretty sure i found it on Google's Android development website